# uiautomation - Tapping custom view doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ipad, testing, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to automate some tests of my ipad application.

I have a scrollview which contains a custom view.

- The custom view overwrites the drawRect and has a TapRecognizer.
- The custom view is created into the code and I have set this properties

```
myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[myView setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
[myView setAccessibilityLabel:@"myView"];
```

- The custom view is added to the scrollview with

```
[myScrollView addSubview:myView];
```

Everything works smooth both on device and on simulator: tapping on the view, the tap recognizer callback is called and the custom view can draw something at the tap point.

I would automate the view test and then I need to simulate user's taps on myView.

In the uiautomation script I have something like this:

```
myView = circuitScrollView.elements()[0];       
myView.logElement();
myView.tapWithOptions({x:56, y:576});
```

to simulate a user tap at position x=56 and y=576.

Nothing happens, it seems that myView doesn't receive any tap (just in case, I play a sound into the TapRecognizer but it has never been sounded).

I have tryed this too:

```
myView.tap();
```

no success.

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Fab.

Comment: Try circuitScrollView.logElementTree() to determine which elements are accesable at all. I would guess your custum view is not in that list. This is not the solution to your problem but might be a step to solve it.

Comment: I read somewhere that having containers with accessibility turned on interferes with it's child elements.

Comment: Fabrizio, how were you able to access your UIScrollView?

Answer (score 1):

This may be of some use to you. I wrote a test that taps certain x/y coordinates. Rather than touching the scroll view try tapping the window as demonstrated below.

To do so I wrote:

```
   var window = UIATarget.localTarget(); 
   window.tap({x:x_co , y:y_co});
```

x_co and y_co were my coordinates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you take UIATarget.localTarget() you have a UIATarget, not an UIAWindow. And even so the tap method doesn't accept arguments. Did you test this script?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe myView = circuitScrollView.elements()["myView"] might help instead of myView = circuitScrollView.elements()[0]; ?

Maybe your custom view is not the first element in the element tree of your circuitScrollView...